# How to save/store multi dimensional list of objects in an Android Application?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

If someone could think of a better way to ask this question that would be great as I'm not sure how to best sum it up.

In my application I currently have 3 types of class. A, B and C. None will exist when the app is first ever launched and more of the classes are made over time as the user creates them. They can also be deleted and edited at the users choice.

- My App holds a list of objects A.
- Class A has various arbitrary fields + a list of objects B (Every B will only be in one instance of A).
- Class B has various arbitrary fields + a list of objects C (Every C will only be in one instance of B).
- Class C is just a standard class with arbitrary fields.

What would be the best way to save the instances of these classes?

My current method would be to hold the main list of objects A in an extended Application class and then save the serialized list Object as a SharedPreference or in a database. Then load/save it up whenever the app restarted or paused etc. Would this be a good idea?

I know how to use SQL on android at a basic level and would use this if not for the multiple dimensions present. Is there a way to make it work with a database?

Any other advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question is pretty unanswerable.  Do the objects need to be passed between activities/services?  Do they last forever or are they temporary?  Do they come from user input, a db, a webservice?  DO you normally iterate through them, or do you need to search on certain fields?  WHich ones?  Do you ever need to map A->C?  Do reverse mappings of C->B?  Delete data?  Add data?  If we don't know how they're used, we can't give you a good answer.

Comment: Sorry @GabeSechan, I've tried explaining things a bit better in my edit. Basically every class A, B and C will be something the user creates and will be editable/deletable at their will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This screams database to me.  The fact it has multiple layers makes it BETTER for a db than it would be for a shared preference.  This is what SQL and relational databases were made to do-  describe relations and hierarchies between data.

What you want is a db with 5 tables

TableA holds all the tableAs.
TableB holds all the tableBs.
TableC holds all the tableCs

TableABMap  has 2 columns  parentID and childID.  parentID is a foreign key that maps to a row in tableA.  childID is a forieng key that maps to a row in tableB.  If you are about order, add a 3rd column (order).

TableBCMap works the same, but for tables B and C.

To get all the Bs in A you would just do a simple subquery  "SELECT * from TableB WHERE id in (SELECT childid from TableABMap where parentid= object_a_you_want)"

I think you should probably learn a bit of SQL for this.  Its an extremely powerful tool if you know even just the basics.  My suggestion would be not to hide behind a library and use it to do the work-  you need to actually understand this kind of stuff to use it effectively.

Comment: This is a good well written answer, my question mainly arose from my lacking of SQL knowledge and therefore how I could use a Database to store data in this kind of structure, which your answer helped explain.

Comment: Hi again, I've been working on my app and have come to a thought. Instead of having Tables BCMap and ABMap, would it be possible to instead, just have an extra column in B that states the id of the object A they are a member of? And the same with C, have an extra column with the id of the object B they are a member of?

Answer (score 0):

In one of our production apps we use [Cupboard](https://bitbucket.org/qbusict/cupboard/wiki/withDatabase). It is pretty simple to use, and will handle a majority of your needs. Does a great job of abstracting out the SQL and other mess. Not really an "answer" but a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [green-dao ORM](http://greendao-orm.com). The relationships you describe can be easily implemented with it. No SQL knowledge needed.

Comment: He still needs SQL knowledge-  he needs to design the schema at the very least.  Nor is suggesting that someone with no knowledge of databases use these kind of tools a good idea-  its like giving somebody the keys to an airliner and telling him autopilot will do all the work for him, then not mention it won't actually land the plane.

Comment: I think db schema design is not "SQL knowledge".

Comment: It absolutely is.  Please tell me how you design a schema without knowing relational databases and the methods of querying them?

Comment: You cannot design a schema without knowing relational databases. But that is not what I'm saying. With green-dao I can design a db schema without knowing any CREATE statement.